# A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. Lots of free memory though

Tags: sql-server-2012, memory

Having a problem where my SQL Server 2012 SP2 Enterprise server says that most of SQL Server's memory has been paged out to disk but there's over 100GB free (of 256GB).

From there system performance drops to the point where it starts dropping network connections.

Looking in Resource Monitor I see a large amount of Modified memory and lots of disk activity to the page file.

I just don't understand why it's paging if there is a lot of free memory available.

I've tried the Lock Pages in Memory setting which didn't seem to work (about to try again).

Googling the problem only seems to return hits talking about Lock Pages in Memory or situations where there actually was a memory pressure problem.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the MAX Memory setting for your server instance ? Check [this](http://mssqlwiki.com/2012/06/27/a-significant-part-of-sql-server-process-memory-has-been-paged-out/) article to on how to troubleshoot this message.

Comment: Here is the actual error message.  A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 658 seconds. Working set (KB): 35467636, committed (KB): 195477212, memory utilization: 18%. Max Memory is set to 200000MB out of a total of 256GB.  I will read the page you posted but I believe this was one of the ones I have read before that turned out to be no help.

Comment: Is anything other than sql server running on the server ? I have seen antivirus running and causing all sort of weird problems.